# Basic URI (Parsing?)

Tags: vb.net, browser

I have been helped by the good people of stackoverflow many times before, so here's my problem...

I haven't been coding for a GOOD while, and for class, we are going to be starting Visual Basic. Visual Basic is really not that hard, but I am not familiar with it, and can't think of a proper way to do this.

As an exercise, I'm coding a very simple web browser. Here's my issue...

```
    Private Sub Send_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Send.Click
    Dim input As String = TextBox1.Text
    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri(input))
```

If the user types "www.youtube.com" in the address bar, they throw an exception (I presume because there is no http:// at the beginning) However, I can't simply add "http://" to the beginning of the string, because then there is the chance for a double up.

How can I check the string for "http://" and add it accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
Dim value As String = Mid(input, 1, 7)

if value = "http://" then
    'you don't need to modifie the url
   else
   'you add your http:// string normaly
EndIf
```

Hope this can help you
PS: sory I corrected some mistakes I maid

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression to validate the [URL/URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
 Dim pattern = "http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?"
 Dim Inputurl = "http://www.abc.com/aa"

  If Regex.IsMatch(Inputurl, pattern) Then
     '            
  Else
     '      
  End If
```

Or use String.StartsWith() method,

```
 If Inputurl.StartsWith("http://") Then
       '
 End If
```